# Why we need to create second object

Tags: c#, linked-list

```
public class Solution {
    public ListNode MergeTwoLists(ListNode a, ListNode b) {
        ListNode result = new ListNode(-1);
        ListNode current = result;
        ListNode l1 = a;
        ListNode l2 = b;

        while(l1 != null && l2 != null) {
            if(l1.val < l2.val) {
                current.next = l1;
                l1 = l1.next;
            } else {
                current.next = l2;
                l2 = l2.next;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }

        if(l1 != null) {
            current.next = l1;
        } else {
            current.next = l2;
        }

        return result.next;
    }
}
```

Hi, I am working on a leetcode problem of merging two linked list, this was a solution I found in the disuss section, it works, but I dont understand why we need to create a second object and assign the first to the second to get the job done, it dosent work when i used result.next direcly

Comment: I is same reason why you sort you need a temp variable.  When you sort to swap two items you do temp = A, A = B, B = A.  If you just do A = B you loose the value of A.

Comment: @jdweng temp i understand, but here if i use result.next instead it does not work, its a linked list right, result.next means the next one

Answer (score 0):

Because result is a reference to the beginning of the list, while current is always at the end (as it is where new elements are added at each step).

If you use lists, instead of nodes, you don't need another object.

Answer (score 0):

You are right this 'result' object is really useless, you throw it away at the end of this routine. It makes the algorithm simpler/faster and avoids some more tests. If ListNode is a struct, than you shouldn't worry. The `new ListNode` is not doing anything real. If it's a class, we could think a second time, if we could avoid it.

```
    ListNode current;
    ListNode l1 = a;
    ListNode l2 = b;

    ListNode result; // here we save the former result.next as result

    if (l1!=null && l2!=null)
    {
        if(l1.val < l2.val) 
        { 
            result = l1; 
            current = l1 = l1.next;
        }
        else 
        {
            result = l2;
            current = l2 = l2.next;
        }
    }



    while ( ....)
    {
         /* unmodified */
    }

    return result;
```

This is only for your understanding, to see the alternatives. This code is faster, cause it skips the `new`  (in case of ListNode is a class), but longer than your code.

Answer (score 0):

Because ***current*** is actually doing the merge process, and finally it will be at the end of the result list, while ***result.next*** is the real head of the result list needs to be returned.